# How to sort after occurence of the / character in a text file Linux console

Tags: linux, sorting, console

Say that I had a list of entries in a text file:

- Apple/bcd
- Pear/abc
- banana/def
- orange/cde

and I wanted to sort these entries in the console by what comes after the "/" so they were:

- Pear/abc
- Apple/bcd
- orange/cde
- banana/def

How do I use the sort function to sort this way without having columns there?
And by only using the sort function, no piping other commands?
I can only sort by the word before the "/".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sort -t / -k 2,2 _file_
```

The `-t /` says the field separator is the `/` character.  The `-k 2,2` says to sort on field 2, which would be the characters after the first `/`.